# Can a single input single output neural network with y=x as activation function reflect non-linear behavior?

Tags: neural-network, set

I am currently learning a little bit about neural networks. One question I can't really get behind is about how neural networks reflect non-linear behavior. From my understanding there is no possibility to reflect non-linear behavior **inside** a compact set using a neural network.

For example if I would take the function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609347/can-neural-networks-approximate-any-function-given-enough-hidden-neurons):

```
y = x^2
```

and I would use a neural network with a single input and single output the best the neural network could do for each compact set [x0...xn] is a linear function spanning from one end of the set to the other, as at the end all calculations inside the net are linear.

Do I have some misunderstanding about this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANN's capabilties to model non-linear behaviour arise from the (usually) non-linear activation function. 
If the activation function is linear, then the process of training the network is just another way to create a linear (or multi-linear) fit of input and output data.

Comment: Hi Harald, thanks for your answer! So how would a sigmoid activation function getting us closer to the desired behavior of y = x^2?

Comment: Hi Axel, the references given by asakryukin are helpful. In my own words and limited understanding: with input of a bias neuron and the x from the input, you have already two sigmoid functions super-imposed. Depending on the size of the interval, that may be enough (within a certain accuracy limit) to approximate the curve. For larger intervals in x and more accuracy, more hidden layer nodes would add more snippets being superimposed. Fiunction fitting with basis-functions....

Answer (score 1):

Activation function in neural networks is exactly the part, that brings non-linearity. If you use linear activation function, then you cannot train non-linear model (thus fit quadratic or other non-linear functions).

The part, I guess, you are interested in is Universal Approximation Theorem, which says that any continuous function can be approximated with a neural network with a single hidden layer (some assumptions on activation function are applied thou). Take into account, that this theorem does not say anything on optimization of such a network (it does not guarantee you can train such a network with a specific algorithm, but only that such a network exists). Also it does not say anything on the number of neurons you should use.

You can check following links, to get more details:
Original proof with sigmoid activation function: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.441.7873&rep=rep1&type=pdf

And a more friendly derivation: http://mcneela.github.io/machine_learning/2017/03/21/Universal-Approximation-Theorem.html